# Backbone.js - Unable to fetch data for collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm currently having problems with fetching data for a collection. It gives this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

router.js:

```
var App = App || {};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'homePage'
  },

  homePage: function() {
    var airplanesCollection = new App.Airplanes();
    airplanesCollection.fetch().then(function(){
      var airplanesView = new App.AirplanesView({ collection: airplanesCollection});
      $(".container").html(airplanesView.render().el);
    });
  }
});

App.router = new App.Router();
```

The collection file airplanes.js:

```
var App = App || {};

App.Airplanes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Airplane,
  url: '/airplanes'
});
```

The model file airplane.js:

```
var App = App || {}

App.Airplane = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/airplanes'
});
```

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could tell me where I went wrong.

Many thanks,

Freddy.

Comment: Where does exactly this error rises (line number)?

Comment: Check to see if airplainesCollection,fetch() is actually returning a jqXHR object. (see http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). I'd guess that you've got some problem that is causing that to fail, and your call to .then() is actually undefined.

Comment: Sorry hindmost, it arises at this line: 
airplanesCollection.fetch().then(function(){

Comment: Well, then it seems that the page that contains the router.js code isn't also loading the airplanes.js and airplane.js (I'd merge those two, btw).   Show the HTML for the page that includes all those files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that `airplanes.js` is loaded/running before `airplane.js`.  In that case, the code ...

```
App.Airplanes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Airplane,
  url: '/airplanes'
});
```

... is setting the `model` of the Collection to be `undefined`.  That would give you a `TypeError` when attempting to call `fetch()` on the Collection.

In the short term, try combining the files into a single one & ensure the Model is defined prior to the Collection.  In the medium-term, look at RequireJS to do truly module Javascript -- it'll save you a huge amount of headache in the future.